# Firebase / Angularfire2: nested data nodes in firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

i've got a firebase database. a node called /config// which holds userspecific data. i now want to add a subtree to the userdata with a list of cars, like /config//cars/:

```
"config" : {
    "NE5AwHcxKofMPKRCAvny5Re4MtG3" : {
      "geburtstag" : "2017-06-04",
      "nachname" : Mueller",
      "cars" : {
        "-Krr2-DC1uoqCvgVJhFL" : {
          "name" : "Ford Mustang"
        },
        "-Krue4_5kJQhis-3Qg1X" : {
          "name" : "Toyota Supra"
        }
      }
    }
```

i created a observable binding to /config/

```
this.$ref = this.database.object('/config/' + uid);
this.data = this.$ref.subscribe();
```

i can access the data of the main config-node and bind it with angular, but a ngFor on the Cars subnode doesn't work. Am i structuring my data wrong or do I need some kind of mapping here?

the html part:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let car of data.cars | async">
    {{car.name}}
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: please share the html that contains the ngFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `data` to your subscription while you should be assigning it to the observable:

```
cars: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
this.cars = this.database.list(`/config/${uid}/cars`);
```

Now you can call your `async` data in your `ngFor` loop:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let car of cars | async">
  {{ car.name }}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: thank you, that works. it was just too obvious to see.

but why doesn't it work this way, too?

this.config = this.database.object(`/config/${uid}`); 
<ion-item *ngFor="let car of config.cars | async">

Comment: because that's an object - not an array. you cannot use `ngFor` in an object.

Comment: why is it an object when i access the tree through /config/${uid} -> config.cars and an array when i access it through /config/${uid}/cars -> cars? its the same data?

Comment: when you call the `db.object()` method you're retrying an object with data for a specific user - firebase database is just a `JSON` file, so you'll get just an object in doing so. when you need a list of objects (array), then you can use the `db.list()` method from `angularfire`. that will convert a list of objects into an array. the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#querying) explains it better.

Comment: I get the error: Cannot find name 'uid' sure that this syntax is still up to date?

Comment: It sounds silly, but are you sure you're defining your `uid` somewhere? :P