# Angular4 / AngularFire2 get (db.list) from nested JSON

Tags: json, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I got a restaurant inside this is a tip:

> Here the JSON Structure: http://prntscr.com/gn5de8

So i try first to get the data inside my repeated restaurant like this:

```
<p *ngFor="let tip of restaurants[item.$key].tips" [innerHTML]="tip.description"></p>
```

But this just dont works.

So i try to make a extra get in the component.ts:

```
public restaurants: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
public tips: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.restaurants = db.list('/restaurants');
    this.tips = db.list(`/restaurants/${key}/tips`);
}
```

And tryed then to repeat them with:

```
<p *ngFor="let tip of tips | async" [innerHTML]="tip.description"></p>
```

But here i get a error with the second line in the constructor: "Cannot find name 'key'" What is wrong in my syntax? and is that what i try to do, the correct way to solve this?

Here the html and the ts files if you need to take a look:

> HTML: https://pastebin.com/6rEmmrXZ
> TS: https://pastebin.com/e5CnPqYp
>
> Here the source where i find the informations for my second try:
> [Firebase / Angularfire2: nested data nodes in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772562/firebase-angularfire2-nested-data-nodes-in-firebase)

best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you aren't defining the `key` variable anywhere. One way to accomplish what you want is mapping the restaurant lists, then convert the `tips` object into an array for every restaurant:

```
this.restaurants = db.list('/restaurants')
  .map(restaurants => restaurants.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    tips: Object.keys(item.tips)
      .reduce((acc, key) => [...acc, item.tips[key]], []);
  });
));
```

Don't forget to import the `map` operator (`rxjs/add/operator/map`). Then, in your HTML just iterate over the restaurant list:

```
<div *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants | async">
  <div *ngFor="let tip of restaurant.tips">
    <p [innerHTML]="tip.description"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I don't recommend that approach. I think you should rethink your data structure and database calls.

The way you're doing now, you'll call the entire list of tips along with the restaurant list. That will become too expensive. You should separate the tips list:

```
- tips
  - $restaurantKey
    - $tipKey
      ...data
```

That way, you can call the tips list separately - only when it's needed. Also, I don't see the point for loading the entire list of tips along the list of restaurants. That could be a huge problem if your app grows and you end up having several tips for every restaurant.

Instead, you could just have a summary of tips. Once a restaurant is selected, then you display the tips for that restaurant only - instead of loading everything at once.

Comment: hmmm i tryed but there is any syntax problem in the code that you posted. this is my first project where i write my own typescript code. thats why my skills are meh. :P Can you please check again the code that you submit? but i think i understand the problem after reading your answer.

Comment: I'm not taking any jobs, sorry. What error are you getting? I'd also suggest creating a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/). It's much easier to help that way.

Comment: I tryed my best to import the app to StackBlitz, but something is wrong there... I cant make it running: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-site But here you can see the whole ts code.

Comment: I'll try to have a look later but here's just one tip: don't import the whole thing over there, that's really hard to debug. Just create a minimal component to reproduce your bug - in your case, a component to display the list of restaurants and tips.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. i did a new one that contain only the relevant stuff: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kambx3?file=sites%2Fsite-restaurants%2Fsite-restaurants.component.ts When you open browser console you get the $key error. And can you tell me, it is normal that the data loads so slowly? i mean the angular Page loads. and he get the data 1 ore 2 sek later, and he throw alot console errors. When he get the data then he dont throw any more error. The page looks strange to while he wait for data...